# CK_CHAR vs CK_BYTE in PKCS#11?

Tags: pkcs#11, cryptoki

Does PKCS#11 intend `CK_CHAR` and `CK_BYTE` to have identical semantics, or is `CK_CHAR` intended to imply printability?

The standard PKCS#11 type header defines `CK_CHAR` in terms of `CK_BYTE` and says "character" instead of "value":

```c
/* an unsigned 8-bit value */
typedef unsigned char     CK_BYTE;

/* an unsigned 8-bit character */
typedef CK_BYTE           CK_CHAR;
```

Does this guarantee that every `CK_CHAR` (and array of `CK_CHAR`s) is within the printable range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: section 1.3, table 3 of PKCS#11v2.40 establishes that `CK_CHAR` is always printable (in ANSI C encoding, which is ASCII).

[image]

Comment: Don't forget the CK_UTF8CHAR.

Comment: Yep; the standard is much more explicit about that being printable (or more generally human consumable).